# How do I test Vue method?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, modal-dialog, vue-component

I am using Vue-js-modal.

On my template I have this:

```
<modal name="hello-world">
  hello, world!
</modal>
```

On my Vue, I have a method like this:

```
showModal() {
    this.$modal.show('hello-world');
}
```

How can I test this method (showModal)?

Answer (score 1):

In general in Vue you would use `refs` to access the DOM like so:

```
<modal ref="$myModal" name="hello-world">
  hello, world!
</modal>

...
methods: {
   testModal(){
     this.$refs.$myModal.show()
    }
}
```

Then if your modal pops up it works!

Comment: I would like to know how to do unit-test. Sorry for not being clear.